# how to unit test global variable which has been changed by calling a function with jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have a util.ts file and it contains methods and global variables.

utils.ts:

```js
global_sub: GlobalSub[];
export const updateSub = (value: Value) => {
global_sub.push({type: 'value', id: value.id})
}
```

utils-test.tsx:

```
updateSub(value);
expect(global_sub.length).tobe(1)
```

I want to use jest to test the function updateSub and test if the value of global_sub has been update when the updateSub has been called. the code but the global_sub.length always 0.

Comment: is `global_sub` accessible to the test? i.e. its not contained in the function or class?

Comment: yes, it is export const global_sub:GlobalSub[]

Comment: So in your test file you are importing both `global_sub` and `updateSub` ?

Comment: yes, I import global_sub and updateSub in the test

Comment: `{type: 'value', id: 0}` Add this object in your file (not test file) and see if that works as expected to rule out you dont have importing issues.

Comment: ok, thx Rikin, I find the problem. I use stomclient in the updateSub method and stomclient point to null to cause the global_sub.length always 0

Comment: This is why global variables are so tricky!